# Change the reference of an instance in List

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question about assignment.

```
public class A {}

public class AHolder
{
  public A AnInstance;
}


void Change()
{
 A anotherInstance=new A();
 anotherInstance.aField="bla";
 A anotherInstance2=new A();
 anotherInstance2.aField="blabla";
 List<AHolder> aList= new List<AHolder>();
 aList.add(new AHolder(){AnInstance=anotherInstance});
 aList.add(new AHolder(){AnInstance=anotherInstance});
 aList.add(new AHolder(){AnInstance=anotherInstance});
 anotherInstance=anotherInstance2;

}
```

How can I implement the code that ensures the changes of all AnInstance values in aList, when anotherInstance changed without using loop?

Update:after executing the code lines above ,i'm trying to get "blabla" value from aList[0].AnInstance.aField.Is it possible?

Comment: You can't. The reason is that *you are actually only changing the value of a local variable*; your `AHolder` instances know nothing about local variables. They know that you passed them an instance, but don't care where you got it from. Describe the problem you are trying to solve, not a specific attempt at solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using a wrapper class instance, instead of referencing directly to the `AHolder` instance, but think if you really need this extra indirection layer, as it would make your code less readable.

I expect the following sample explains how to do it:

```
public class MyData { public string Value; }
public class MyRef  { public MyData Instance; }

void Change()
{
 var dataFoo = new MyData() { Value = "foo" }
 var dataBar = new MyData() { Value = "bar" }
 var referer = new MyRef()  { Instance = dataFoo }

 var list= new List<MyRef>();
 list.add(referer);
 list.add(referer);
 list.add(referer);
 // for i=0 to 2 -> list[i].Instance.Value = "foo"

 referer.Instance = dataBar;
 // for i=0 to 2 -> list[i].Instance.Value = "bar"
}
```

Comment: I guess,it solves the question above.Thank you.  But I couldn't describe the problem clearly.In addition to question,In    MyRef class,i need 5 props which 3 of them have to be different,and 2 of them have to be same  in whole list.Do you have any suggestion in this case?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's not possible (i.e you can use static attributes, for common values), but the constraints you explained let me think that maybe you are struggling with a mismatched model...